# Mirroring files locally in background

Tags: backup, background-process

Context:

Say I have two workplaces. Currently, I carry a laptop along, and have external HDs staying in these workplaces to hold backups. Now, I'm given the opportunity to have a desktop in both workplaces, so I'd rather carry along an external HD (USB SSD) holding my files, and use the internal HDs of the desktops to hold backups.

Question:

How to mirror files in the background? The mirroring needs not be "instantaneous" during the work day, but after shutdown the copies should be exact, and I'd like to be able to shutdown in a reasonable time.

With my current knowledge I'd be able to add an rsync command to crontab and to the logout process, but (i) I don't know how to avoid conflict if the two commands happened to be ran at the same time, and (ii) there may be something more efficient?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thx. Do you know if lsyncd will (i) do a first sync at boot (when changing workplace the files there will be out of sync) (ii) do a final sync at shutdown?